# Функции в си. Массивы

Tags: c, массивы, функции, случайные-числа, арифметика

Нужно написать функцию, которая считает среднее арифметическое среди элементов
массива размера N. Проблемы возникли их за оптимизации. Решил сразу заполнить массив в самой функции, но компилятор выдает ошибку. Что у меня не так ? Помогите пожалуйста.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int alg(int N, int massif[N]) 
{   
    float summ = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++) 
    {
        massif[i] = rand() % 10;
        printf("%d ", massif[i]);
        summ += massif[i];
    }
    float float_sum = summ;
    float middle = float_sum / N;
    return middle;
}


int main () 
{   
    srand(time(NULL));
    int N;
    float middle;
    printf("SIZE = ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    int massif[N];

    middle = alg(N, massif[N]);
    printf("%.2f", middle);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего - без массива. Вот код с абсолютно той же функциональностью:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int N;
    float middle = 0;
    printf("SIZE = ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int j = rand() % 10;
        printf("%d ",j);
        middle += j;
    }
    printf("%.2f", middle/N);
}
```

Но если очень нужно исправить именно ваш код... Тогда вот:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int alg(int N, int *massif)
{   
    float summ = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++) 
    {
        massif[i] = rand() % 10;
        printf("%d ", massif[i]);
        summ += massif[i];
    }
    float float_sum = summ;
    float middle = float_sum / N;
    return middle;
}


int main () 
{   
    srand(time(NULL));
    int N;
    float middle;
    printf("SIZE = ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    int * massif = malloc(sizeof(int)*N);

    middle = alg(N, massif);
    printf("%.2f", middle);

    free(massif);
    return 0;
}
```